# What are standard ways to show that your functions are connected to a certain JSON data structure?

Tags: json, node.js, parsing

I've a JSON file with a structure  that is not yet set; it may grow complex. 
I want to keep track of what the functions think the data structure is.

*What are standard/smart ways to show that your functions is connected to a certain data structure?*

Right now, I'm using a **_comment**  in the json file to keep a version number, and then keeping that version name as a **comment in each function** that uses it. Full example below.

**travel.json**

```
{
  "_comment" : "version 1.0"
, "name" : "Tom Sawyer"
, "travel" : [{
   "id" : "1"
,  "location" : "San Francisco"
  }, {
   "id" : "2"
,  "location" : "London"
  }]
}
```

**Two functions to parse: travel.json**

```
fs = require('fs');

function get_json() {

    var file = __dirname + '/travel.json';
    data = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
    var json_obj = JSON.parse(data);
    return(json_obj);

 };

function get_location(json_obj) {
    // "version 1.0"

    var new_obj = {};
    json_obj.content.forEach(function(item) { 
        new_obj[item.id] = item.location;
    });
    return ( new_obj );

};

// Run 
console.log('Locations: ', get_location( get_json() ));
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain why you are doing this? It looks a bit like defensive programming. If you are creating an API that other people will depend on you could version the url of the API instead of the JSON. Something like yoururl/api/1/locations, yoururl/api/2/locations, etc

Comment: I'm learning so everything feels a bit defensive.;D I like your suggestion! It's more elegant and easier to manage. There are no little comment lines scattered around to handle.

Comment: Defensive programming and premature optimization are the devil.

Comment: Yes, yes. As I'm learn. Any good reading - blog posts - on examples of how to not be a defensive programmer?

Comment: @Pickels Can you put what you wrote in your first statement into an answer? I'll accept it so the question has an official green check mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks a bit like defensive programming. If you are creating an API that other people will depend on you could version the url of the API instead of the JSON. Something like yoururl/api/1/locations, yoururl/api/2/locations, etc

Comment: Super. Smart recommendation.